# React - State is not updating when it is supposed to, why is react doing this? (not retaining)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hi so I'm trying to grab some json from an api and then populate a table, pretty simple stuff.
What's happening is that I can see the "tableData" state being updated as each new row comes in, I'm also logging every time "tableData" is updated, yet maybe .5 seconds after its all done my "tableData" is empty again (check console screenshots)

[image]

```
const [bigChartData, setbigChartData] = React.useState("data1");
  const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([]);

  const setBgChartData = (name) => {
    setbigChartData(name);
  };

  const getData = () => {
    axios.get("URL")
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data.items.forEach(item => {
          setTableData(oldData => [...oldData, {
            data: [
              { text: item.title },
              { text: "asd" + item.url },
              { text: "some links..." }
            ]
          }]);
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(tableData);
    }, 3000);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Table data updated:");
    console.log(tableData);
  }, [tableData]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not iterate through each row inside getData() method instead try following code

```
const getData = () => {
    axios.get("URL")
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data.items.map(item => {
                return{
                       data: [
                          { text: item.title },
                          { text: "asd" + item.url },
                          { text: "some links..." }
                      ]
                };
          });

          setTableData(data) 

      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
   
}
```

or if you have already some data in `tableData` then

```
 setTableData([...tableData, data])
```

Comment: I need to iterate over the rows as I need to deconstruct the data I'm getting from the API, only need certain things

Comment: Nope still dosn't work, thanks for trying tho, your data const is just returning undefined

Comment: @WillHelstrip So sorry, instead of `forEach` it should `map` function, I edit my answer again check now

Comment: I've already tried that, same thing happens it constructs the correct array for the state and sets it but it gets unset